# How does one capture the recognised text from Echo?

Tags: alexa

I know that some skills can capture spoken text, such as when adding to to-do lists and shopping lists, and third party skills can also do this, eg. [SMS with Molly](https://smswithmolly.com/).

So, how do they do this?  Is there an API call that captures the recognized text and stores it somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Custom skills](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/overviews/understanding-custom-skills) can capture text and send them to your Skill's API.

If you're not completely familiar with how Alexa Skills work, here's a brief summary:

- First, you [register your Skill with Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/registering-and-managing-alexa-skills-in-the-developer-portal), providing an [*intent schema* and *sample utterances*](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/defining-the-voice-interface#introduction). The intent schema defines which actions can be performed, and the [*slots*](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference) for custom data to be sent to your API. The sample utterances provide examples of how a user can trigger each intent.
- When the user activates your Skill, Alexa will try to match what they said to one of your skill's sample utterances. If it **does** match, it will send an HTTPS request to your server to ask for a response.
- Your server provides a response (if all goes well) and then Alexa will give feedback to the user who triggered your skill.

The [`AMAZON.LITERAL` slot](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#literal-slot-type-reference) allows you to accept virtually any input. Note that currently it is only supported in the English (US) region—English (UK) and German skills cannot use `AMAZON.LITERAL`.

Your intent schema might look like this:

```json
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "SaveTodo",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Todo",
          "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And your sample utterances might be like this:

```
SaveTodo remind me to {fetch the shopping|Todo}
SaveTodo remind me to {write my English essay|Todo}
SaveTodo remind me to {buy some dog food tomorrow|Todo}
```

When using `AMAZON.LITERAL`, you need to provide *lots* of sample utterances—at least one sample for each possible length of input, but ideally more. The Amazon documentation suggests that you should be aiming for hundreds of samples for slots where you could accept various types of inputs.

It does seem a little tedious, but if you don't do this, it's unlikely that your skill will recognise text well. You could perhaps generate sample utterances from customer data (so long as personal information is removed beforehand!) so that the most common utterances are in your samples—I suspect Alexa will be slightly biased towards recognising utterances similar to the samples.

Amazon [discourage `AMAZON.LITERAL` slots though, and would prefer you to use custom slot types](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/migrating-to-the-improved-built-in-and-custom-slot-types#literal), which require you to list the possible inputs. It's important to remember that:

> A custom slot type is not the equivalent of an enumeration. Values outside the list may still be returned if recognized by the spoken language understanding system. Although input to a custom slot type is weighted towards the values in the list, it is not constrained to just the items on the list. Your code still needs to include validation and error checking when using slot values.

Comment: I believe Amazon are keeping the literal slots as many developers protested against their loss.  But using the literal slot will prevent your skill from being published as Amazon don't want developers the ability to "listen in" on users.  But you can still use it in a private skill.

Comment: @GrahamChiu: I get the impression that literal slots are still allowed even in published skills (see [this blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution): "Based on developer feedback we will not remove the LITERAL slot type and you can continue to submit skills that include its functionality."). I've not tried it myself though, so if you can confirm either way, that might be helpful for future visitors.